# Getting the error "/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found" and other errors when I type gmake in Qt directory

Tags: linux, path, redhat-enterprise-linux, make, shared-libraries

I installed the offline installer "Qt 5.8.0 for Linux 64-bit (766 MB)" and also the tar.gz file for Linux and mac users from the following link:

https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

The tar.gz file I downloaded was `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar`

(My system in RHEL 6.6).

I then transferred both the tar.gz file and the installer to my Desktop and I began referring to this link for additional instructions:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-building.html

On my desktop, I typed these commands:

```
gunzip qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar.gz        
tar xvf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar
```

This created the directory `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0`. I then used `cd` to go inside this directory and I typed `./configure`.

Upon this, I was first asked if I wanted the Open-Source edition or the Commercial one and I chose the Open-Source edition. I was then asked if I agreed with the GPL and LGPL licenses and I chose yes again. In the very end I was shown this message:

```
Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'gmake'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'gmake install'.
Qt will be installed into /usr/local/Qt-5.8.0

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

After reading this, I wrote `gmake` on the command line. After processing `gmake` for several hours, I got these erros:

```
gmake[4]: Entering directory `/root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/examples/scxml/trafficlight-widgets-static'
/root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/examples/scxml/trafficlight-widgets-static/qscxmlc_wrapper.sh ../trafficlight-common/statemachine.scxml --header statemachine.h --impl ./statemachine.cpp
/root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/bin/qscxmlc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/bin/qscxmlc)
gmake[4]: *** [statemachine.h] Error 1
gmake[4]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/examples/scxml/trafficlight-widgets-static'
gmake[3]: *** [sub-trafficlight-widgets-static-make_first] Error 2
gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/examples/scxml'
gmake[2]: *** [sub-scxml-make_first] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/examples'
gmake[1]: *** [sub-examples-make_first] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml'
gmake: *** [module-qtscxml-make_first] Error 2
```

**Why am I getting these errors? What should I do to resolve them?**

EDIT:

When I type gcc -v I get the following output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/root/gcc-4.8.2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /root/Downloads/objdir/../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=/root/gcc-4.8.2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

I read the errors carefully and realized that the root of my errors is this line:

```
/root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/bin/qscxmlc: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /root/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtscxml/bin/qscxmlc)
```

I referred to a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386651/how-to-fix-usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) and based on that I typed the following command:

`strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` and it gave me the following output:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

**So apparently, GLIBCXX_3.4.14 isn't on my system and it is looking for it. How can I get around this problem?**

Comment: It's fairly easy to replace /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13 with a later version. And create the new link libstdc++.so.6 . ... *If* you aren't using the g++ compiler. I.e. g++ depends on libstdc++.so.6.0.13 . .... Example : libstdc++-4.8.2-15.el6.x86_64.rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTldGbExoYXliYkU/view?usp=sharing ... Instead of installing a package, you can also do : Unpack the rpm and copy libstdc++.so.6.0.xx to /usr/lib64/.

Comment: @KnudLarsen What will happen if one is using the g++ compiler?

Comment: g++ is OK with e.g. libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19 . The issues I remembered must have been : Installing the alien rpm package.  Unpack rpm : `unPack_rpm.sh` : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2EyWFpOdEhDOGM/view?usp=sharing